# DelphiXE2 : How to Display Data From Database to NextGrid

Tags: sql, database, delphi, delphi-xe2

I've searched around, ask my local teacher at my school. But there is no way i could find how to display data from database to NextGrid. I used SELECT * but it doesnt shown on the next grid.

```
ZQuery1.Close;
ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ZQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM tb_siswa';
ZQuery1.Open;

NextGrid1.ClearRows;
x:= 0;

while not ZQuery1.Eof  do
begin
  NextGrid1.AddRow();
  NextGrid1.Cell[0,x].AsString := ZQuery1.Fields[0].AsString;
  NextGrid1.Cell[1,x].AsString := ZQuery1.Fields[1].AsString;
  NextGrid1.Cell[2,x].AsString := ZQuery1.Fields[2].AsString;
  NextGrid1.Cell[3,x].AsString := ZQuery1.Fields[3].AsString;
  NextGrid1.Cell[4,x].AsString := ZQuery1.Fields[4].AsString;
  inc(x);
  ZQuery1.Next;
end;
ZQuery1.Close;
```

Any support please?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `NextDBGrid`, which is designed to be connected to a dataset? Or a reason you're not looking at the code for the demos for NextGrid, which are specifically designed to show you how to use it? Or that you're not looking in the `NextGrid` [forums](http://www.bergsoft.net/forum) for support?

Comment: oke .. what the different of NextGrid or NextDBGrid ?

Comment: The reason NextDBGrid has **DB** in it's name is because it's designed to attach to a DB (database), just like TDBGrid is designed to attach to a database. They both have `DataSource` properties (that a normal `TStringGrid` or `TNextGrid` don't have) to connect to a `TDataSource`, which handles the connection between the `TDataSet` (query or table) and grid automatically. Read the Delphi documentation on `TStringGrid` and `TDBGrid` to understand the differences between them.

Comment: i ever use NextGrid to connect database , it can . 
so , please help me to use NextDBGrid . i finish to try but error because undeclare identifier:D

Comment: what must i add in uses to declare NextDBGrid ? sorry i'm newbie in delphi

Comment: Look at the demos! They're supplied for you to use to learn about the components. Drop a NextDBGrid on the form instead of the NextGrid. If you don't have a NextDBGrid on your component palette, you didn't install it and you need to do so.

Comment: i have nextdbgrid . then next please ...

Comment: OK. One last time, and that's it. Drop the NextDBGrid and a `TDataSource` on your form. Set the `NextDBGrid.DataSource` property to `DataSource1`. Set the `DataSource1` `DataSet` property to your query. Set your query's `Active` property to True. You should have data in the grid. Now **use the NextGrid documentation and demos**. :-)

Comment: i'm so sory ... dataset can't be true . 

i want to show data in table from localhost

Comment: Then set the `Active` to true at runtime. Where the data comes from doesn't matter. The steps to connect the dataset to the grid remain the same. **Use the demos and documentation.** I've explained the exact steps to display the data in the grid, and it's up to you to adapt it to your specific needs. If you want someone else to do all the work, you need to hire a contractor to write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

On the nex suite component page, you have the `NxDataCellSource` component.  Place it on the form. Place the next grid on the form.  In the `NxDataCellSource` properties, change the datasource to the one you are using, `ZQuery1`.  Change the Associate properties to `NextGrid1` (or other name you have associated to nextgrid).  Set active to true and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

**i'm use NextGrid1.RowCount-1 this code,dont need manual increment value**

```
while not ZQuery1.Eof  do
begin
  NextGrid1.AddRow();
  NextGrid1.Cell[0,NextGrid1.RowCount-1].AsString := ZQuery1.Fields[0].AsString;
  Next;
end;
```